# JavaScript anonymous function callback and redux-saga .next()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I've been going through several JavaScript concepts now, including a several react conveys, and there's a couple of questions that I am wondering and wishing to get help from you guys.

Suppose we have a function name sum:

```
const sum = (a,b) => a + b
```

Question 1:
I've seen a lot of anonymous functions being called to call another function, I am wondering the reason why we do that instead of calling that specific function directly. For example:

- Instead of using

```
onClick = {sum}
```

we use:

```
onClick ={() => sum}
```

- Also, in the react course, I am wondering why do we call mapDispatchToProps like:

```
Increment: () => dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'})
```

but not:

```
increment: dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'})
```

---

Question 2:

- When do we use sum() or sum in the click event, for example:

```
onClick = {sum()} OR onClick = {sum}
```

---

Question 3:

- As we know that Redux-Saga implements generator function, but as from what I know, generator function when it has more than one yield, it requires next() in order to go on.
  However, in Redux-Saga, I don't see the use of next(), is that because the Sagas has already automatically called next() in it's function?

Thanks guys. Much appreciated!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts Please split your questions into multiple posts next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question 1 and 2, the `onClick` property expects a event handler (which is a function definition) that has the `event` as the first parameter and should not return anything.

When the button is clicked, the `onClick` function invokes, passing the `event` as the first argument.

Read more at [Handling Events in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b

// an `event` will be passed as the first argument, the second argument gets undefined
onClick={sum} 

// you could opt out the `event` parameter and call `sum` with your arguments
onClick={() => { sum(5, 10) }} 
onClick={() => sum(5, 10)} // this will return the value of `sum(5, 10)` to the caller of onClick, which is not useful since the caller don't expect that

=> Using anonymous callback gives you the ability to call the function with specific arguments

// invalid usages, calling the function immediately which will assign the returned value to `onClick`, and the that returned value is not a function definition
onClick={sum(5, 10)}
increment: dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'})
```

For the question 3, `redux-saga` acts as a generator runner that has handled calling next() for you. You only need to define the generator function (in combination with using their `redux-saga` effects)